# CefSharp Touch Event Handeler

Tags: c#, touch, focus, cefsharp

I am using **Cefsharp version 37** (c#).

How can I make **CefSharp browser** responsive to **mouse clicks as a touch taps**.

I want to raise the Touch keyboard of win 8.1 when a text control inside **The CefBrowser gets focused.**

I didn't find any event raised `on-focus` of control inside the CefBrowser Browser.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Technically, you should be able to use this code in your initialization to enable touch events

```
var settings = new CefSettings
    {
        BrowserSubprocessPath = "CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe"
    };
    settings.CefCommandLineArgs["touch-events"] = "enabled";

    Cef.Initialize(settings);
```

See if that works for you, it appears that WPF support is still not there. Follow this thread for more info

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/228

Comment: Thanks, i have succede doing it by using RegisterJsObject method and injecting a c# object into the javascript that will do the actions when the events occur.